# Error when using conditional statement in docker file

Tags: python, docker, gradle, devops, rest-assured

Hi I am setting up my automation framework to pick file from two different locations based on a tag that's being set during runtime by devops. Now my task is to update my docker file to add that conditional statement but i am getting the error as unknown instruction: ELSE. Can someone help please whats wrong with this docker conditional statement

```
ARG My_Arguement

RUN if [ "$My_Arguement" = "Test2" ] ; then
 ENTRYPOINT ["/ci/nightly/scripts/fargate_test.sh"];
 else  ENTRYPOINT ["/ci/daily/scripts/fargate_test.sh"] ; fi
```

Is this not the correct if else conditional statement for docker?
Error i am getting is `unknown instruction: ELSE`
I am using gradle with Spring boot for my automation framework

Comment: You need to add the backslash (\\) at the end of the line as continuation character.

Comment: You can't set `ENTRYPOINT` inside a conditional like that.  If you change it to `CMD`, though, it's very easy to override it when you run the image.  (It's usually considered better practice to run the same image in testing and production.)

Answer (score 1):

Dockerfiles can't have conditionals like that.

To achieve what you want you could instead have a `docker-entrypoint.sh` script like

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$My_Arguement" = "Test2" ] ; then
  /ci/daily/scripts/fargate_test.sh;
else
  /ci/nightly/scripts/fargate_test.sh;
fi
```

and change your Dockerfile to

```
ARG My_Arguement
ENV My_Arguement $My_Arguement
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh .
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```